# Construction of area 2-form on S^2 using Hopf Map

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

given a complex scalar field  $\phi(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ which is a map $\phi:S^3 \mapsto S^2$ where $S^3 = R^3 \cup \{\infty\}$ and $S^2 = C^1 \cup \{\infty\}$

The area two form of $S^2$ normalized to unity, expressed in stereographic co-ordinates is given by

$A = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\frac{d\phi^*\wedge d\phi}{(1+\phi^*\phi)^2}$

This is given in a paper about electromagnetic knots, I would like to know how to get to this area two form, I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but am not sure what you're asking: 1. Where the formula for $A$ comes from? 2. How to evaluate $A$ for a particular choice of $\phi$? 3. Something else? Could you please edit your question to clarify this, and perhaps also say how the question arises and (if it's homework) what tools you have available and what you've tried? Thank you.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Hi andrew, thanks for the reply, I have edited the post, and hopefully it makes a bit more sense. I want to understand where this area two-form comes from, Internet searches have not been much help. This is not homework.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\newcommand{\dd}{\partial}\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}\newcommand{\Cpx}{\mathbf{C}}\newcommand{\dd}{\partial}$If $w = u + iv$ denotes a complex coordinate on the unit sphere $S^{2} \subset \Reals^{3}$, then [stereographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection) from the north pole $(N = (0, 0, 1)$ is given by
$$
f(u, v) = \frac{(2u, 2v, u^{2} + v^{2} - 1)}{u^{2} + v^{2} + 1}
  = \frac{(2w, |w|^{2} - 1)}{|w|^{2} + 1}.
\tag{1}
$$
(By a small abuse of notation, $\Reals^{3}$ has been idenfitied with $\Cpx \times \Reals$.) The parametrization (1) identifies the unit sphere with the Riemann sphere $\Cpx \cup \{\infty\}$. A straightforward calculation (see below) shows that the induced area form on $\Cpx$ is
$$
\omega = \|f_{u} \times f_{v}\|\, du \wedge dv
  = \frac{2i\, dw \wedge d\bar{w}}{(|w|^{2} + 1)^{2}}.
$$
(Out of habit, I've used $\bar{w} = u - iv$ instead of  $w^{*}$ to denote complex conjugation.) Normalizing to unit area gives
$$
A = \frac{\omega}{4\pi}
  = \frac{1}{2\pi}\, \frac{i\, dw \wedge d\bar{w}}{(|w|^{2} + 1)^{2}}
  = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\, \frac{d\bar{w} \wedge dw}{(|w|^{2} + 1)^{2}}.
\tag{2}
$$
(Moving the $i$ from the numerator to the denominator introduces a sign, which is absorbed by swapping the order of the differentials. Also, $|w|^{2} = \bar{w}w$.) If $w = \phi(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3})$ is a complex scalar field, substitution in (2) gives your formula.

---

**Edit**: Here's a fairly detailed sketch, in real coordinates. By the quotient rule,
$$
\frac{\dd f}{\dd u}
  = \frac{2(-u^{2} + v^{2} + 1, -2uv, 2u)}{(u^{2} + v^{2} + 1)^{2}},\qquad
\frac{\dd f}{\dd v}
  = \frac{2(-2uv, u^{2} - v^{2} + 1, 2v)}{(u^{2} + v^{2} + 1)^{2}}.
$$
The cross product is
\begin{align*}
\frac{\dd f}{\dd u} \times \frac{\dd f}{\dd v}
  &= \frac{4}{(u^{2} + v^{2} + 1)^{4}}
  \left\lvert\begin{array}{@{}ccc@{}}
  i & j & k \\
  -u^{2} + v^{2} + 1 & -2uv & 2u \\
  -2uv & -u^{2} + v^{2} + 1 & 2v \\
  \end{array}\right\rvert \\
  &= \frac{4}{(u^{2} + v^{2} + 1)^{4}}
  \bigl(-2u(u^{2} + v^{2} + 1), -2v(u^{2} + v^{2} + 1), 1 - (u^{2} + v^{2})^{2}\bigr) \\
  &= -\frac{4}{(u^{2} + v^{2} + 1)^{3}}\, (2u, 2v, u^{2} + v^{2} - 1) \\
  &= -\frac{4}{(u^{2} + v^{2} + 1)^{2}}\, \frac{(2u, 2v, u^{2} + v^{2} - 1)}{u^{2} + v^{2} + 1}.
\tag{3}
\end{align*}
Since (1) has unit magnitude (as a parametrization of the unit sphere), (3) has magnitude $\dfrac{4}{(u^{2} + v^{2} + 1)^{2}}$.

To convert this to complex form, use $w = u + iv$ to write $dw = du + i\, dv$, $d\bar{w} = du - i\, dv$, and
$$
dw \wedge d\bar{w} = -2i\, du \wedge dv,\qquad
i\, dw \wedge d\bar{w} = 2\, du \wedge dv,
$$
so that
$$
\omega = \|f_{u} \times f_{v}\|\, du \wedge dv
  = \frac{4\, du \wedge dv}{(u^{2} + v^{2} + 1)^{2}}
  = \frac{2i\, dw \wedge d\bar{w}}{(|w|^{2} + 1)^{2}}.
$$
Incidentally, the round metric $g$ on $\Cpx \simeq \Reals^{2}$ induced by stereographic projection is conformally Euclidean:
$$
g = \frac{4\, (du^{2} + dv^{2})}{(u^{2} + v^{2} + 1)^{2}}.
$$
This "explains" why the area element is the indicated multiple of the Cartesian area form, and (in other contexts) is useful for calculating the Gaussian curvature of the round sphere.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Andrew. I'm having trouble understanding the "straightforward calculation". I've only just discovered differential forms, and google doesn't seem to helpful on the matter. But the rest makes sense.

Comment: In case it helps, the calculation is an ordinary surface element calculation from vector calculus: Compute the (vector-valued) partial derivatives of $f$, take their cross product, and then calculate the magnitude, $\|f_{u} \times f_{v}\|$, to get the "area density".

Comment: Separately, the exterior calculus of differential forms is less intimidating than it first appears; most things boil down to the chain rule, or to anti-commutativity of the wedge product. It's a pleasant exercise, for instance, to calculate $d\eta$ for a $1$-form $\eta = \eta_{1}\, dx + \eta_{2}\, dy + \eta_{3}\, dz$, and to discover the curl operator "magically" appearing.

Comment: So I've been trying to work this out for the past 2+ hours. I cant figure out how you can change 2u,2v (2 co-ordinates) just to 2w(1 co-ordinate). I took $df_1/du$ and  $df_1/du$ and the same for d/dv, where $f_1 = (2w/(|w|^2+1))$ and $f_2 =(|w|^2-1/(|w|^2+1)$ and i get zero upon taking the jacobian determinant. Sorry for being annoying!

Comment: @johnahh: Real computation added. :) To do the computation "honestly" in complex coordinates, one should write the rightmost (complex) expression in (1) as three component functions, then take partials with respect to $w$ and $\bar{w}$....

Comment: What an amazing answer, if only i could upvote you more than once. Thnak you for taking so much time to explain this to me.

Comment: You're very welcome; glad to be of help!